# Is it possible to use Git extension or Git GUI to manage the files on a remote linux ftp server like a local repository

Tags: linux, git, ftp, bitbucket, git-extensions

I have my site stored on a remote Linux server and I use FTP to download, edit, and re-upload them. I am currently able to use the git bash to connect and upload the files (like a local repository) to bitbucket (my remote repository) but I was wondering if its possible to use one of the graphical git programs to connect to the server and be able to push/pull/manage the changes just to make my life simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local clone of that Linux server repo, you can use it in combination of any GUI ([SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/), [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/windows/), ...) installed locally.

That is easier than trying to install a GUI in an environment where you only have headless (ie shell or ftp) access.

Comment: Yea the problem is that the site only runs when on the server so we will constantly have to be syncing between the local and server when editing as we can't view and edit it locally mainly due to DB restrictions, so nothing works properly.